# adding debouncetime in Input element event, angular10

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using a simple input in angular.

```
           <ng-template #searchinput>
              <mat-form-field class="w-100" floatLabel="never">
                <input matInput placeholder="Search" [id]="'search_'+col.columnDef" (input)="searchChange($event.target.value, col.columnDef)">
              </mat-form-field>
            </ng-template>
```

i want to add debounceTime in the event.

```
searchChange(event, colName) {
    console.log(event, colName);
    event.pipe(
      debounceTime(300), 
      distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(value => console.log(value)
    );    
  }
```

But this is not working `ERROR TypeError: event.pipe is not a function`. Need some help.

Comment: What does the console say? What is the error?

Comment: added the error, event is basically the text not observable

Comment: Approving the right answer would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `event` is actually the value from your input field. If you want to add `debounceTime`, you have to do the following;

```
private value$ = new Subject<string>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.input$
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )
    .subscribe((input: string) => {
      console.log(input);
    }
}

searchChange(input, colName) {
  this.input$.next(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the Marek W's one. Another aproach is using a FormControl, and subcribe to valueChanges just

```
control=new FormControl();
ngOnInit()
{
 this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )
    .subscribe((input: string) => {
      console.log(input);
    }
}
```

And

```
<input [formControl]="control">
```

Comment: Or use `@viewChild` on the input and then `fromEvent()` to create a stream directly from the DOM event. FormControl gives you a lot of extras though, so I like this answer best. I also think binding a FormControl with the directive looks cleaner and is easier to understand.